# Send button on chatbot does not work once clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, chatbot

Problem Description:
I am trying to create a chatbot using Python and JavaScript by following a YouTube tutorial. The chatbot user interface (UI) appears correctly, and the button to open the chatbox popup is functioning properly. However, when I enter a message in the input field and click the send button, nothing happens, and the message doesn't appear in the chatbox. I'm seeking assistance in understanding the reason behind this behavior.

Code:

Here is the code for app.py, responsible for running the application:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from chat import get_response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("base.html")

@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    text = request.get_json().get("message")
    # TO-DO: check if text is valid
    response = get_response(text)
    message = {"answer": response}
    return jsonify(message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=5001)
```

And here is the code for app.js, which contains the chatbot implementation:

```
class Chatbox {
  constructor() {
    this.args = {
      openButton: document.querySelector(".chatbox__button"),
      sendButton: document.querySelector(".send__button"),
    };

    this.state = false;
    this.messages = [];
  }

  toggleState(chatBox) {
    chatBox.classList.toggle("chatbox--active");
  }

  onSendButton(chatBox) {
    var textField = chatBox.querySelector("input");
    let text1 = textField.value;
    if (text1 === "") {
      return;
    }

    let msg1 = { name: "User", message: text1 };
    this.messages.push(msg1);

    fetch($SCRIPT_ROOT + "/predict", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: text1 }),
      mode: "cors",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((r) => {
        let msg2 = { name: "Sam", message: r.answer };
        this.messages.push(msg2);
        this.updateChatText(chatBox);
        textField.value = "";
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
        this.updateChatText(chatBox);
        textField.value = "";
      });
  }

  updateChatText(chatBox) {
    var html = "";
    this.messages
      .slice()
      .reverse()
      .forEach(function (item, index) {
        if (item.name === "Sam") {
          html +=
            '<div class="messages__item messages__item--visitor">' +
            item.message +
            "</div>";
        } else {
          html +=
            '<div class="messages__item messages__item--operator">' +
            item.message +
            "</div>";
        }
      });

    const chatMessage = chatBox.querySelector(".chatbox__messages");
    chatMessage.innerHTML = html;
  }

  display() {
    const { openButton, sendButton } = this.args;
    const chatBox = document.querySelector(".chatbox__support");

    openButton.addEventListener("click", () => this.toggleState(chatBox));

    sendButton.addEventListener("click", () => this.onSendButton(chatBox));

    const inputNode = chatBox.querySelector("input");
    inputNode.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
      if (event.key === "Enter") {
        this.onSendButton(chatBox);
      }
    });
  }
}

const chatbox = new Chatbox();
chatbox.display();
```

Furthermore, here is the HTML and CSS code for the chatbot present in base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Chatbot</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="chatbox">
        <div class="chatbox__support">
            <div class="chatbox__header">
                <div class="chatbox__image--header">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/circled-user-female-skin-type-5--v1.png" alt="image">
                </div>
                <div class="chatbox__content--header">
                    <h4 class="chatbox__heading--header">Chat support</h4>
                    <p class="chatbox__description--header">Hi. My name is Sam. How can I help you?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="chatbox__messages">
                <div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="chatbox__footer">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Write a message...">
                <button class="chatbox__send--footer send__button">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chatbox__button">
            <button><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/chatbox-icon.svg') }}" /></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var $SCRIPT_ROOT = "{{ request.script_root|tojson }}";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='app.js') }}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Lastly, the CSS code for styling the chatbot is provided in the style.css file below:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 100%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

*,
html {
  --primaryGradient: linear-gradient(93.12deg, #581b98 0.52%, #9c1de7 100%);
  --secondaryGradient: linear-gradient(
    268.91deg,
    #581b98 -2.14%,
    #9c1de7 99.69%
  );
  --primaryBoxShadow: 0px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  --secondaryBoxShadow: 0px -10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  --primary: #581b98;
}

/* CHATBOX
=============== */
.chatbox {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 30px;
}

/* CONTENT IS CLOSE */
.chatbox__support {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #eee;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  z-index: -123456;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

/* CONTENT ISOPEN */
.chatbox--active {
  transform: translateY(-40px);
  z-index: 123456;
  opacity: 1;
}

/* BUTTON */
.chatbox__button {
  text-align: right;
}

.send__button {
  padding: 6px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* HEADER */
.chatbox__header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: orange;
}

/* MESSAGES */
.chatbox__messages {
  margin-top: auto;
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.messages__item {
  background: orange;
  max-width: 60.6%;
  width: fit-content;
}

.messages__item--operator {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.messages__item--visitor {
  margin-right: auto;
}

/* FOOTER */
.chatbox__footer {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}

.chatbox__support {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  height: 450px;
  width: 350px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}

/* HEADER */
.chatbox__header {
  background: var(--primaryGradient);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: var(--primaryBoxShadow);
}

.chatbox__image--header {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.chatbox__heading--header {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: white;
}

.chatbox__description--header {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  color: white;
}

/* Messages */
.chatbox__messages {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.messages__item {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  max-width: 70%;
}

.messages__item--visitor,
.messages__item--typing {
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

.messages__item--operator {
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  background: var(--primary);
  color: white;
}

/* FOOTER */
.chatbox__footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  background: var(--secondaryGradient);
  box-shadow: var(--secondaryBoxShadow);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.chatbox__footer input {
  width: 80%;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-align: left;
}

.chatbox__send--footer {
  color: white;
}

.chatbox__button button,
.chatbox__button button:focus,
.chatbox__button button:visited {
  padding: 10px;
  background: white;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here's my chat.py file:

```
import random
import json


import torch

from model import NeuralNet
from nltk_utils import bag_of_words, tokenize

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

with open('intents.json', 'r') as json_data:
    intents = json.load(json_data)

FILE = "data.pth"
data = torch.load(FILE)

input_size = data["input_size"]
hidden_size = data["hidden_size"]
output_size = data["output_size"]
all_words = data['all_words']
tags = data['tags']
model_state = data["model_state"]

model = NeuralNet(input_size, hidden_size, output_size).to(device)
model.load_state_dict(model_state)
model.eval()

bot_name = "Sam"

def get_response(msg):
    sentence = tokenize(msg)
    X = bag_of_words(sentence, all_words)
    X = X.reshape(1, X.shape[0])
    X = torch.from_numpy(X).to(device)

    output = model(X)
    _, predicted = torch.max(output, dim=1)

    tag = tags[predicted.item()]

    probs = torch.softmax(output, dim=1)
    prob = probs[0][predicted.item()]
    if prob.item() > 0.75:
        for intent in intents['intents']:
            if tag == intent["tag"]:
                return random.choice(intent['responses'])
    
    return "I do not understand..."


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Let's chat! (type 'quit' to exit)")
    while True:
        # sentence = "do you use credit cards?"
        sentence = input("You: ")
        if sentence == "quit":
            break

        resp = get_response(sentence)
        print(resp)
```

Also, this is the error I get when I press the send button:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: $SCRIPT_ROOT is not defined
at Chatbox.onSendButton (app.js:26:11)
at HTMLButtonElement. (app.js:77:53)"

Additional Context:

I have implemented a chatbot based on the tutorial, but when I enter a message and click the send button, nothing happens. I have reviewed the code, and it appears that the onSendButton() function is not being triggered correctly. I expect the message to be sent to the server using the fetch() function and then added to the chatbox messages using the updateChatText() function.

I would appreciate any assistance in identifying why the messages are not displaying after clicking the send button. Thank you!

Comment: I see two problems.  First, `$SCRIPT_ROOT` is definitely defined.  Second, `$SCRIPT_ROOT` is never mentioned in `app.js`.  Are you SURE that's the current copy of the file?

Comment: whoops sorry, I just reedited my post to include the current copy of the app.js file which includes $SCRIPT_ROOT - The error still stands however

Comment: If you omit the `var` in `var $SCRIPT_ROOT = ...;`, does that fix it?

Comment: Hi I tried removing the var in var $SCRIPT_ROOT, however I still get the same error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $SCRIPT_ROOT is not defined
    at Chatbox.onSendButton (app.js:26:11)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (app.js:77:53)"

Comment: Simple typo.  Because you have `request.script_root|tojson` in the `$SCRIPT_ROOT` definition, Flask is automatically ADDING the quotes for you, and you are doubling them.  You either need to (a) remove your quotes in that line, or (b) remove the `|tojson`.  Extra credit to you for including (nearly) the whole source so I could recreate it here.  Your code now works for me.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help :) I tried option a) where I removed the quotes but encountered additional errors:

"Property assignment expected" at line 48, column 29.
"',' expected" at line 48, column 38.
"',' expected" at line 48, column 50.
"Declaration or statement expected" at line 48, column 63.
"Declaration or statement expected" at line 48, column 64., also tried option b) which worked, I removed the tojson and I see my own messages popping up when I click send  however I don't get a reply from the bot itself...did the bot reply when you tried it using your own code?

Comment: Yes, but of course you didn't share `chat.py`, so I hardcoded a "me" response, and that certainly came through.

Comment: Ok, I reedited to include chat.py. I still don't seem to be getting a reply on my bot... is there an issue with my chat.py?

Comment: If you change the line to `response = 'hello'`, do you see that?  Divide and conquer.

Comment: If I run the chatbot on my terminal it works, however it does not seem to display on my site when I enter "http://127.0.0.1:5001"....

Comment: I'm not willing to install `torch` to find out.  As I said, if I change the call to `get_response` so that it is `response = 'hello'`, I see "hello" in the chat.  That tells me the web hookup is correct, and the problem has to be in the chat code.